# How to find the first consecutive days of a dataset in SQL?

Tags: presto

Im trying to select only the first consecutive dates in SQL from the table

[image: see picture]

The final results should look like this

[image: see picture]

This is the example of the initial table.

This is the initial table I have.

```
> Campaign Code Current Date    Campaign Start Date Days Since Campaign
> Launch    Next DaTe   Next date - Current Date domestic campaign
> 1 10/01/2022  10/01/2022  0   11/01/2022  1 domestic campaign
> 1 11/01/2022  10/01/2022  1   12/01/2022  1 domestic campaign
> 1 12/01/2022  10/01/2022  2   13/01/2022  1 domestic campaign
> 1 13/01/2022  10/01/2022  3   14/01/2022  1 domestic campaign
> 1 14/01/2022  10/01/2022  4   15/01/2022  1 domestic campaign
> 1 15/01/2022  10/01/2022  5   16/01/2022  1 domestic campaign
> 1 16/01/2022  10/01/2022  6   17/01/2022  1 domestic campaign
> 1 17/01/2022  10/01/2022  7   18/01/2022  1 domestic campaign
> 1 18/01/2022  10/01/2022  8   19/01/2022  1 domestic campaign
> 1 19/01/2022  10/01/2022  9   30/01/2022  11 domestic campaign
> 1 30/01/2022  10/01/2022  20  31/01/2022  1 domestic campaign
> 1 31/01/2022  10/01/2022  21  01/02/2022  1 domestic campaign
> 1 01/02/2022  10/01/2022  22  19/05/2022  107 domestic campaign
> 1 19/05/2022  10/01/2022  129 20/05/2022  1
```

And I am looking to select only the first consecutive dates which would return the following:

```
Campaign Code   Current Date    Campaign Start Date Days Since Campaign Launch  Next DaTe   Next date - Current Date
domestic campaign 1 44571   44571   0   44572   1
domestic campaign 1 44572   44571   1   44573   1
domestic campaign 1 44573   44571   2   44574   1
domestic campaign 1 44574   44571   3   44575   1
domestic campaign 1 44575   44571   4   44576   1
domestic campaign 1 44576   44571   5   44577   1
domestic campaign 1 44577   44571   6   44578   1
domestic campaign 1 44578   44571   7   44579   1
domestic campaign 1 44579   44571   8   44580   1
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please add your examples as text to the question. Also please show what have you tried.

Comment: I have added the example as text, I tried Lead and Lag function but I dont know how I can select the campaigns by using only the first consecutive dates

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` function subtracted from 'Next Date' to create groups for consecutive dates per campaign code, then use `DENSE_RANK` function to select only the first consecutive group for each campaign code.

```
With get_groups As
(
  Select *,
    Date_add('day', -ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By CampaignCode Order By NextDate), NextDate) As grp
  From table_name
),
get_ranks As
(
  Select *,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (Partition By CampaignCode Order By grp) As rnk
  From get_groups
)
Select CampaignCode, CurrentDate, CampaignStartDate,
   DaysSinceCampaign, NextDate, Nextdate_CurrentDate 
From get_ranks 
Where rnk = 1;
```

You may try to google "gaps and islands problem in SQL" for more details about this problem.

Side Note: ('Days Since Campaign', 'Campaign Start Date' and 'Next date - Current Date') can be easily calculated from other columns, so you don't need to store them in the table.

Comment: Thanks so much for this Ahmed. Is there another way to calculate the interval as the function interval is not available in Postgre SQL.

Comment: You are welcome, What DBMS you are using, MySQL, SPARK or Postgre ! you tagged the question with MySQL !

Comment: Im currently using Presto SQL. i did tagged the question with MySQL, my apologies

Comment: Try to replace the `date_sub(...) as grp` with `date_add('day', -ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By CampaignCode Order By NextDate), NextDate) as grp`. https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#interval-functions